# JQuery .load() Autenticación del servidor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

EL problema es el siguiente.
Estoy implantando una pagina externa en una sección de mi pagina con el siguiente código (Jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#boton").click(function(event) {
            $("#capa").load("http://www.miserver.com/algo.php", function(response, status, xhr) {                    

                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Error!, algo ha sucedido: ";
                    console.log(xhr);
                    $("#capa").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pero al hacerlo el me lanza un error de autorización.

> 401 Authorization Required

Investigando encontré que podría agregar la siguiente linea podría solucionarlo lo cual no fue del todo correcto (No funciono).

```
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('user' + ":" + 'pass'));
```

Que segun quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#boton").click(function(event) {
            $("#capa").load("http://www.miserver.com/algo.php", function(response, status, xhr) {                    
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('user' + ":" + 'pass'));
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Error!, algo ha sucedido: ";
                    console.log(xhr);
                    $("#capa").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

No he podido encontrar algo que me funcione.
Alguna observación? Por favor ayuda.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: habría que ver que hay en `http://www.miserver.com/algo.php` y cual es la configuración del servidor (apache/nginx pueden filtrar el acceso según esquemas de autenticación), en caso de apache puede estar en la definición del server/virtualhost, en el .htacces ó el `algo.php` puede decidir en base a `N`razones devolver ese estado.

Answer (score 0):

### Utilizar $.ajax() en lugar de $.load()

la función `.load()` de [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) no soporta anexar **headers** a la petición **ajax**, por lo que te sugiero cambiar tu codigo javascript.

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton").click(function(event) {
   $.ajax("http://www.miserver.com/algo.php", {
    type: "GET",
    headers : {
     add1:"Authorization: Basic " + btoa('user' + ":" + 'pass')
    }
   })
   .then(
    // done:
    function(data) {
     $("#capa").html(data);
    },
    // fail:
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
   );
  });
 });
</script>
```

Ten en cuenta que este código solo funcionara si cuentas con las credenciales necesarias para reemplazar los literales: `'user'` & `'pass'` respectivamente.

Adicionalmente debes verificar si el servidor al cual quieres acceder permite el **Intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado** o [CORS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercambio_de_recursos_de_origen_cruzado) (**Cross-origin resource sharing**, en sus siglas en inglés), de otro modo no podrás hacerlo con **ajax** ya que el **Browser** impone limitaciones al respecto

Espero te sirva de ayuda ;))...

Comment: Hola que tal, gracias por responder. Acabo de realizar una prueba y nada, aun me niega la autenticación y claro que el usuario que utilizo tiene las credenciales. Eso por un lado, por otro lado como necesitaba esto algo rápido lo desarrolle en otro lenguaje "C#" donde logre realizar con éxito la autenticación del usuario pero me parece interesante lograr solucionar este codigo en Javascript.

Comment: Debes verificar si el servidor al cual quieres acceder permite el **Intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado** o [CORS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercambio_de_recursos_de_origen_cruzado) (Cross-origin resource sharing, en sus siglas en inglés), de otro modo no podrás hacerlo con **ajax** ya que el **Browser** impone limitaciones al respecto.